# error while exporting query result to custom dto

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

**Query**:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.fin.iota.model.dto.TimeSeriesDto(date_trunc('hour', PC.time), sum(PC.count)) from UserCount as PC where PC.time >= :currentDate and PC.time < :nextDate group by date_trunc('hour', PC.time)")
    List<TimeSeriesDto> generateTimeSeries(@Param("currentDate") Timestamp currentDate, @Param("nextDate") Timestamp nextDate);
```

**DTO**:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TimeSeriesDto {
    Date dayHour;
    long pcounts;
}
```

**Error**:

```
Error creating bean with name 'userCountDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.fin.iota.repository.user.UserCountDao.generateTimeSeries(java.sql.Timestamp,java.sql.Timestamp)!
```

What is it that I am missing or what is incorrect?

Comment: `date_trunc` is an invalid function for JPQL. As per all JPA docs

Comment: The interesting part is code builds on my system, but doesn't build on my friend's

Comment: And I am able to execute this query on my system. 
How can I add date_trunc so that JPQL can use it?

Comment: Not interesting at all. The JPA spec is very clear on what is a valid function. Use anything else and you are non-portable, and using features of a particular JPA provider (which one?). You don't "add date_trunc so that JPQL can use it", JPQL != SQL. Any JPQL is converted into SQL, and you don't say what that is. aka debugging

Comment: Now, I am using - `(FUNCTION('date_trunc', 'hours', PC.time))`, and getting the same error.